# Xcode 11.2.1; iOS 13.0 - Getting 404 error on existing link sometimes on only one iPhone - works fine on every other iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, networking, http-status-code-404

raw httpresponse printed down here - the link returns a json when printed into browser, deleting and reinstalling the app fixes this problem.The only difference between this iPhone and the other ones I have is that this one has iOS 13.0. Is there any way to fix this without updating? thanks

```
Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x2820f8da0> { URL: http://myurlgoeshere.nope/api/finished-reports } { Status Code: 404, Headers {

    "Accept-Ranges" = (
        bytes
    );

    Connection = (
        "Keep-Alive"
    );

    "Content-Length" = (
        1882
    );

    "Content-Type" =   (
        "text/html"
    );

    Date = (
        "Tue, 26 Nov 2019 08:19:42 GMT"
    );

    Etag = (
        "\"643ec5-75a-1ee0b00\""
    );

    "Keep-Alive" = (
        "timeout=5, max=100"
    );

    "Last-Modified" = (
        "Wed, 30 Jul 2014 08:33:16 GMT"
    );

    Server = (
       "Apache/2.2.2 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.2 OpenSSL/0.9.7a PHP/5.1.4"
    );

} })
```

Comment: this is just a header; not a response json

Comment: This is what I get in the response,there is no data returned, jsondecoder says that the data is corrupted or not valid json

Comment: You need to ask your backend team about they can help to solve this.